# Akka ActorSelection

Tags: akka

I have the following lines:

```
val c = context.actorSelection("akka://ActorSystem/user/AAA/BBB/*")
c ! MessageNotification(message)
```

but the message doesn't seem to get delivered anywhere.

Meanwhile, this works:

```
val c = context.actorFor("akka://ActorSystem/user/AAA/BBB/CCC")
c ! MessageNotification(message)
```

Any reason why my actorSelection doesn't resolve to anything but a single ActorRef can get resolved and work?

Comment: Actor Selections travel along logical actor paths, e.g. starting from the current actor. I'm not at a real computer now, so cannot decide which kind of bug you are seeing (i.e. whether your code is supposed to work), so please open a ticket about this.

Comment: It most definitely does not support addresses, only relative paths to the context.

Comment: Good to know!  Will play around with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

actorFor sends message to the specific actor system that will receive your message, as for the actorSelection, it sends message to all the actor system in the path.